# Send form data as json to a server

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a server running that accepts a `POST` request with input in the form of json. Now, I am trying to create a simple html page that will trigger the `POST` request once the user clicks on `Submit` button. My code is as follows

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<br/><br/><br/><br/>
<body>
<script>
function submitform (form) {
   var object = {};
   form.forEach((value, key) => {object[key] = value});
   var json = JSON.stringify(object);
   return json;
}

</script>
<form action="http://localhost:9000/parse" method="post">

    <h3>Enter url :</h3>
    <input type="text" name="url" placeholder="http://google.com" style="width: 300px"><br>
    <br/><br/>
    <input type="submit" name="Get Website Statistics" style="width: 20em;  height: 2em;" onclick="submitform()">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

I want the server to receive the request with payload

```
{
    "url" : "https://www.example.com"
}
```

However, I receive the response from server as

```
For request 'POST /parse' [Expecting text/json or application/json body]
```

My curl request is as follows

```
curl 'http://localhost:9000/parse' -H 'Connection: keep-alive' -H 'Cache-Control: max-age=0' -H 'Origin: http://localhost:63342' -H 'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1' -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.87 Safari/537.36' -H 'Sec-Fetch-User: ?1' -H 'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3' -H 'Sec-Fetch-Site: same-site' -H 'Sec-Fetch-Mode: navigate' -H 'Referer: http://localhost:63342/html-parser/views/index.html' -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br' -H 'Accept-Language: en-GB,en;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8' -H 'Cookie: Idea-836ae252=9c616505-7e0e-4a1e-bdd0-fa54e473c071' --data 'url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.spiegel.de%2Fmeinspiegel%2Flogin.html&Get+Website+Statistics=Submit' --compressed
```

Can anybody please guide me as to what I am doing wrong here ? TIA

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you didn't include your JSON into the body:

```html
<form action="localhost:9000/parse" method="post">

    <h3>Enter url :</h3>
    <input type="text" name="url" placeholder="http://google.com" style="width: 300px"><br>
    <br/><br/>
    <input type="submit" name="Get Website Statistics" style="width: 20em;  height: 2em;">

</form>
```

Comment: Sorry, but I did not understand your solution

Answer (score 0):

```
 <form action="http://localhost:9000/parse" method="post" onsubmit="return submitform()">
   <input type="submit" name="Get Website Statistics" style="width: 20em;  height: 2em;">
 </form>
```

put onsubmit event inside a form tag.

Comment: Still I get the same error 
Status Code: 415 Unsupported Media Type

Comment: try to add a class - "forma" to your form element and change submitform function as i wrote and also put your onsubmit event in a form tag as i wrote above.
function submitform (e) {
      let formInit = document.querySelector('.forma').elements
      let obj ={};
      for(var i = 0 ; i < formInit.length ; i++){
        let item = formInit.item(i);
        obj[item.name] = item.value;
      }
      let to_json = JSON.stringify(obj);
      console.log(to_json)
      return to_json;
}

Comment: The above solution does not work for me. I have added the curl request that gets generated in chrome. Hope that helps !!!

Comment: I guess my javascript code does not work at all. Ideally, when I run this code, it should log the json to the console, but it fails to do so